# Can I use a normal dll or another language package in Ada?

Tags: dll, package, ada

Currently I am using a hardware that provides me a software package that comes  from a DLL.  They also provide packages in different languages (Java, C++ and Python) with functions from the DLL, so I am programming my app in Java.  I would like to change to Ada but I don't know the way to use the DLL functions or the packages that the company offer me in other languages.  Is there a way to do it?

I know I can extract the function names from the DLL, but I don't exactly know how to convert that into an Ada package, or if I can use the packages already made in other languages in any way.

Comment: Welcome to SO, kindly take a look around and see how to ask a proper question.

Comment: Thank you, I guess this is more specific now

Comment: There are several questions and answers in the Ada section of SO that relate to interfacing languages with Ada. Most of the time, DLL interfaces are made C compatible. In that case, the writing of the Ada specification of the DLL interface (i.e. for the dll `foo.dll`, write `foo.ads`) can usually be done using the `Interface.C` package and its subpackages. You can find some hints about its usage here, or directly into the Interfaces.C source code : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938883/interface-ada-dynamic-library-with-java-using-jna-and-adas-interface-c-packages?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The lazy answer is simply "yes". :-)

The GCC documentation on the subject is here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Using-DLLs-with-GNAT.html

As it says, you also need an Ada specification for the functions in the DLL, you want to use.  You can either write it by hand, or use `gcc -fdump-ada-spec` on the C or C++ header files to have one generated automatically.  The generated specifications are not always beautiful, but they are more likely to be correct than something you write from scratch yourself.

Comment: Better to use `g++ -fdump-ada-spec` (preserves more info, such as parameter names)

Comment: Thanks, I will try to generate the spec